# not able to select all the when checked

Tags: css, rating

hope i can get some help.
First, i'm new in to programming. I found a great tuto on youtube and wanted to recopied it. It works almost fine, but for some reason I don't get the same result.

When the mouse goes hover the stars it only shows some part of it and when i checked ex. 4 stars it only shows the last part of the 4th star.

thans for the help

HTML:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdKw.png)

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Rating Star</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"    referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>5 Star Skills Rating Bar</h2>
    <div class="skills">
        <h3 class="name"> Html</h3>
        <div class="rating">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
            <input type="radio" name="html">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="skills">
        <h3 class="name"> CSS</h3>
        <div class="rating">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
            <input type="radio" name="CSS">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills">
            <h3 class="name"> Javascript</h3>
            <div class="rating">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
                <input type="radio" name="Javascript">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="skills">
            <h3 class="name"> Photoshop</h3>
            <div class="rating">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
                <input type="radio" name="Photoshop">
            </div>
        </div>
       <!--  <p style="color:white">Fournir un commentaire:</p>
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>      --> 
    </div>
    
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```
````

here the css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body    
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #0a2b3c;
}

.container
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.25),
    inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.25),
    8px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    inset -2px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.container h2
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    color: #1f9cff;
}

.container .skills
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.25),
    inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.25),
    8px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    inset -2px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container:hover .skills
{
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.container .skills:hover
{
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 2;
}

.container .skills h3
{
    min-width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container .skills .rating
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.container .skills .rating input
{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .skills .rating input::before
{
    content: '\f005 ';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    font-size: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    color:#030b0f;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .skills .rating input:nth-child(2n + 1)::before
{
    right: 4px;
    left: initial;
}

.container .skills .rating input:hover ∼ input::before,
.container .skills .rating input:hover::before

{
    color:#1f9cff;
}
```

here the result: [image]

I tried like 3x the same video

Comment: You should share your HTML as well that will make your code runnable

Comment: I don’t know how to Adf my HTML can i send it to you via email or something else

Comment: I added a picture of my HTML and it's repeated for CSS, Java etc.

Comment: Take a look at this to see how to add your code: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c

Also, you could add it as a code snippet (i think with `Ctrl + M`) where you can add html + CSS and even run it

Comment: hope you have all you need. and thx for the help. if i can ask is it possible with that structure to send the info to php and show it back to the webpage